# Can I use a character vector with recode() and mutate()

Tags: r, character, dplyr, recode

I have a tbl as shown below:

```
   # A tibble: 6 x 8
  projectRcn projectID projectAcronym role        id name   shortName activityType
       <int>     <int> <chr>          <chr>    <int> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       
1     208327    741617 PROSME-INN     parti~  9.44e8 INSTI~ INMA Buc~ PUB         
2     208327    741617 PROSME-INN     parti~  9.39e8 CAMER~ CCIPH     OTH         
3     208327    741617 PROSME-INN     parti~ 10.00e8 FUNDA~ CRIMM     OTH         
4     208327    741617 PROSME-INN     coord~  9.41e8 AGENT~ ADRSM     OTH         
5     208327    741617 PROSME-INN     parti~  9.41e8 SC IN~ SC INPUL~ PRC         
6     208327    741617 PROSME-INN     parti~  9.54e8 AGENT~ ADRBI     PUB
```

I can use recode() with mutate() to add an extra column, based upon $activityType, called $orgType using the code below:

```
h2020orgs <- mutate(h2020orgs,
                    orgType = recode(activityType,
                          HES = "Higher/Secondary Education Establishment",
                          OTH = "Other",
                          PRC = "Private/For-profit entity",
                          PUB = "Public body",
                          REC = "Research Organisation"))
```

Is there a way to replace the list starting with 'HES = "Higher/Secondary Education Establishment"' with a single vector after 'activityType,'?

I have tried defining a character vector...

```
cordisActivityTypes <- c(HES = "Higher/Secondary Education Establishment",
                         OTH = "Other",
                         PRC = "Private/For-profit entity",
                         PUB = "Public body",
                         REC = "Research Organisation")
```

...and then using this in place of individually typed out character strings:

```
h2020orgs <- mutate(h2020orgs,
                    orgType = recode(activityType,
                                     as.character(cordisActivityTypes)))
```

this throws the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed.
```

Am I trying to over-engineer my use of recode within mutate? Can you suggest an alternative to typing out each individual instruction within recode? When it comes to recoding with many individual instructions the code starts to get very long and unwieldy!

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Hi @akrun I hope this slimmed down head() of my tbl is OK? I'm still not sure how to properly use dput()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a vector, use a `list`

```
cordisActivityTypes <- list(HES = "Higher/Secondary Education Establishment",
                     OTH = "Other",
                     PRC = "Private/For-profit entity",
                     PUB = "Public body",
                     REC = "Research Organisation")
```

and then do the evaluation with `!!!`

```
h2020orgs %>%
             mutate(orgType = recode(activityType, !!! cordisActivityTypes))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @akrun thanks. In the interests of learning, can you explain why we need to use '!!!'? I haven't seen this method anywhere in the literature or stack.

Comment: @geofffest  It is a bang bang bang operator used to evaluate when there are multiple sets of expressions depending on the parameters the function takes.  You can check [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more info